# Passing parameter to Route in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have defined a route which cannot be accessed unless the user has logged in. The code for this is as follows:

```
    const App = ({ userLoggedIn }) => {
return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header userLoggedIn={ userLoggedIn }/>
            <ProtectedRoute path='/content' component={ Day } userLoggedIn={ userLoggedIn } />
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

I am passing the userLoggedIn as parameter as the App is keeping the state of it. I am defining ProtectedRoute in a similar way as the Auth example in React Router documentation.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ userLoggedIn, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={ props => (
    userLoggedIn ? (
      React.createElement(component, props)
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

But userLoggedIn is always null (even when the value is not null before calling the ProtectedRoute).

---

I have created a simpler example which I'm testing in the App. I have added the following line:

```
<TestRoute path='/test' userLoggedIn={ userLoggedIn }/>
```

And created the `TestRoute` component as follows:

```
    const TestRoute = ({ userLoggedIn }) => {
  console.log(userLoggedIn);
  return (
    <Redirect to={{
      pathname: userLoggedIn ? '/yes' : '/no'
    }}/>
  )
}
```

What I see now is than in the console appears `null` twice and then the real value for `userLoggedIn`... I guess the first time the component receives the `null` redirects to `/no` so when the real value "arrives" it doesn't go to `/yes` as it should...

---

How can I access the userLoggedIn param I'm passing? Does anyone has a similar example?

Thanks

Comment: outside your `ProtectedRoute` try to console `this.props.userLoggedIn` to see if you received it.

Comment: If you mean before using ProtectedRoute I can confirm I receive it as I use it in another component Header (I took it out to simplify the question). The Header shows the value of userLoggedIn in the navbar of the application. I will update the question later when I have access to my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after trying several options I found something that works for me an it's even simpler than what I was trying to do.

In the App part where I have the `Router` I have created a `Route` that uses conditional coding:

```
<Route path='/content' component={ userLoggedIn ? Day : LoginPage } />
```

And that's all I need. If the user is logged in it renders the `Day` component, if it is not logged in then it redirects to the `LoginPage`. Maybe it's not the best solution but it works for me.

If someone has a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You access router properties via `props.route` i.e. `props.route.userLoggedIn`.

If your component isn't the top level one you can wrap it in `withRouter` or access it via the `context` in v4 but looks like you won't need to.

Answer (score 0):

For navigation check as your `userLoggedIn` before the user can access the page, I use the `onEnter` method.

```
<Route path='/content' onEnter={userLoggedIn} component={Day} />
```

So your `userLoggedIn` can be like this

```
function userLoggedIn(nextState, replace) {
  // check if your user is logged in
  if (localStorage.getItem('isLogged') !== 'true') {
    // block navigation and redirect to login page
    replace({ pathname: '/login', state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname } });
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps